# How to use mono mcs compiler to target the .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mono

There is a `gmcs` compiler that compile to .NET 2.0

> Common Questions
>
> What is the difference between dmcs, gmcs and smcs
>
> They are the same compiler with three different set of defaults.
>
> - dmcs: references the 4.0-profile libraries (the APIs as defined in .NET 4.0) and supports C# 4.0.
> - gmcs: references the 2.0-profile libraries (the APIs as defined in .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5) and exposes the full C# 3.0 language.
> - smcs: references the 2.1-profile libraries (the APIs defined for Silverlight) and exposes the full C# 3.0 language. This is the compiler used for creating Silverlight/Moonlight applications.

But, I uninstall libreoffice yestoday. then the `gmcs` command goes away too.

I have uninstall the mono

```
sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

when finish install mono.

where still no `gmcs` command.

So, I try to use `mcs` to compile code that target to the .NET 2.0 .

But I don't know how to do this.

For example:

this code

```
using System;

public delegate void MyFunc();

public class Test
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Show...");
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main...");
        Test t = new Test();
        MyFunc f = t.Show;
        f();
    }
}
```

Should not be compiled with the .NET 2.0 platform.
Because `Action Delegate` is not available in .NET 2.0

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I have try add  `-sdk -langversion` params to `mcs` , but the code above still got compiled. NO errors, No Warning...

So, How to use `mcs` compile code target to .NET 2.0

Comment: You said *Should not be compiled with the .NET 2.0 platform. Because Action Delegate is not available in .NET 2.0*. But you're not using Action delegate anywhere. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

mcs help shows the option sdk which accepts the values 2,4,4.5
setting sdk to 2, this way you can target 2

what you need to ensure the compilation against .net 2 is to set the assemblies path to .net 2 path

-lib:"Path to .net 2 assemblies"